# How to obtain selected value from angucomplete-alt?

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to use [Angucomplete-alt](https://github.com/ghiden/angucomplete-alt) - 
autocomplete directive for AngularJS without any luck.
Problem is: selected value from autocomplete list does not update my model.

In Angular application

```
 var app = angular.module("workScheme2App", ['angucomplete-alt']);

workScheme2App.controller('SMSController', function ($scope, $http) {

    this.anketa =
    {
       DeliveryAddress_Province: {
            id: 0,
            name: ""
        }
    };

 };
```

In view:

```
 <angucomplete-alt id="DeliveryAddress_Province" name="DeliveryAddress_Province" 
              pause="400"
              selectedObject="anketa.DeliveryAddress_Province"
              remote-url="../../Client/getListProvince?query="
              title-field="name"
              />  


  remote-url="../../Client/getListProvince?query="
```

MVC controller method in "remote-url" attribute successfully returns JSON array of objects like this:
[{id: 1, name: "Киевская"}, {id:2, name: "Одесская"}]
Dropdown appears and I can select needed value, but after selection exception happened:

Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' used with directive 'angucompleteAlt' is non-assignable!
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$compile/nonassign?p0=undefined&p1=angucompleteAlt
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:63)
    at $get.parentSet (angular.js:7658)
    at parentValueWatch (angular.js:7671)
    at Object.regularInterceptedExpression (angular.js:12838)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:14222)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14493)
    at HTMLDivElement. (angular.js:21427)
    at HTMLDivElement.p.event.dispatch (jquery.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.p.event.add.g.handle.h (jquery.js:2)

I cant figure out how to assign selected to anketa.DeliveryAddress_Province object ? Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in attribute "selectedObject", after i change it to "selected-object" it works properly. Hyphenated attributes transforms in directive to camelCase properties.